# lookup displaying (None)

Tags: 2010, lookup-column

I have a library with a lookup column, when I add a document a edit form is presented and the lookup is available however the first item in the lookup is (none). If I then try to make this a required field then the 1st item in the lookup list is pre-selected.

Both options don't help the user. Is there a way to ensure if none is accidently selected the user is alerted of an error or if I make the column required then I don't want the 1st item as default.

I don't want to edit the form as this removes the auto addition of columns. I have 4 lists I need this action to occur on.

Comment: Try putting a validation formula on the list?

Comment: The column does not show up under the validation section - probably because its a lookup?

Comment: Bah ya, looks to be the case, sorry bout that.